# Differentiation with respect to a ratio

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a function:

$y= 35(α/β)^4-84(α/β)^5+70(α/β)^6-20(α/β)^7$

Is it legitimate to say $x = α/β$, and therefore the derivative with respect to $x$ is:

$140(α/β)^3-420(α/β)^4+420(α/β)^5-140(α/β)^6$

Noting that alpha is a variable and beta is a constant value, and their ratio (and therefore the value of x) in this specific problem is a value between 0 and 1, where 0 is the start of a rotation, and 1 is the end of the rotation.

Sorry that this is super basic, I did this work well over a decade ago, its a long time since I last did any calculus and I feel like I am losing my mind looking back at this. [Slapping it into Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=differentiate%20%2035%28x%29%5E4-84%28x%29%5E5%2B70%28x%29%5E6-20%28x%29%5E7%2C%20where%20x%3Da%2Fb) suggests I was correct, but I'm not sure I trust it or myself! :D

Comment: See chain rule, the derivative of $g(x/m)$ for $x$ is $g'(x/m)/m$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{eqnarray} y & = & 35(\alpha/\beta)^4-84(\alpha/\beta)^5+70(\alpha/\beta)^6-20(\alpha/\beta)^7 \\
& = & 35x^4 - 84x^5+70x^6-20x^7 \\
\frac{dy}{dx} & = & 140 x^3 - 420 x^4 + 420 x^5 - 140 x^6 \end{eqnarray}$

All of the above is valid. We are allowed to create the substitution $x = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, and we are allowed to differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$.

However, we do need to be careful if what we actually want is $\frac{dy}{d\alpha}$. What we would do is apply the chain rule:

$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{dy}{d\alpha} & = & \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{d\alpha} \\
& = & (140 x^3 - 420 x^4 + 420 x^5 - 140 x^6)(\frac{1}{\beta}) \\
& = & \frac{1}{\beta}\left (140 \left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^3 - 420 \left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^4 + 420 \left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^5 - 140 \left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^6 \right)
\end{eqnarray}$